# Archive validation failed with errors Due to Unknown Reasons

Tags: ios, xcode7.2

Archive validation failed with errors

Because of these kinds of errors
Show in image[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyvoo.png)

Comment: I tried again and Again but....

Answer (score 0):

This has been happening recently, its either a bug with xcode or apple, but if you archive and then click export (next to validate), then select "For Apple Store Deployment", this will create an IPA file from your app. Next, in Xcode, go to the top bar under the Xcode menu select "Open Developer Tool" and select the Application Loader. Then select Deliver your App and choose the ipa file you just created and this will send it to the store if it is a valid ipa.

EDIT:

Check in your info.plist (open as source) and make sure you have this key

CFBundleExecutable
    ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}

Also make sure your bundle identifier matches what you have listed on the store.

Comment: but it give some errors although I validate that Archive File

Error#1
ERROR : "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/PicStick.app/AviarySDKResources.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue."

Comment: Error # 2:

ERROR : "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/PicStick.app/AviarySDKResources.bundle/AviarySDKContentResources.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue."

Comment: Error # 3: 

ERROR : "Invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value. The key 'CFBundleSupportedPlatforms' in the Info.plist file in bundle 'Payload/PicStick.app/AviarySDKResources.bundle' contains an invalid value '( "iPhoneSimulator" )'. Consider removing the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key from the Info.plist. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue."

Comment: Error # 4:

ERROR : "Invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value. The key 'CFBundleSupportedPlatforms' in the Info.plist file in bundle 'Payload/PicStick.app/AviarySDKResources.bundle/AviarySDKContentResources.bundle' contains an invalid value '( "iPhoneSimulator" )'. Consider removing the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key from the Info.plist. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue."

Comment: I have the App. I just Test it and Upload to App Store.
Tell me that what kind of these errors? 
It is Related to Coding or some other????

Comment: you arent using any other libraries? I updated my answer

Comment: my client bought code from somewhere and just asks me to upload it

Comment: My Client faced a issue "your account is revoked but apps are there" 
Is this cause any issue???

Comment: its running on my device but giving issues while uploading

Comment: BTW these framework And Libraries are used:

MessageUI.framework
EventKit.framework
EventKitUI.framework
CoreTelephony.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
AVFoundation.framework
AudioToolbox.framework
libz.dylib
UIKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
StoreKit.framework
Security.framework
MediaPlayer.framework
Foundation.framework
AdSupport.framework
QuartzCore.framework
libz.1.2.5.dylib
libsqlite3.0.dylib
OpenGLES.framework
CoreData.framework
Accelerate.framework
CoreLocation.framework
AssetsLibrary.framework
RevMobAds.framework
libGoogleAdMobAds.a
libFlurry_5.4.0.a
libFlurryAds_5.4.0.a